# How to create a pop-up when exiting a view?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm making a photo editing app for school from last semesters project. When a user clicks the back button (in editor mode) which in my case is called "Product Selection" I'd like to have a pop-up come up and say "Do you want to delete everything and go back to product selection?" to see if they want to discard their work, and if the user selects yes, the entire project is discarded and they are put back in the lobby.

Where do I put this code to do this? I found the "Product Selection" button in the min story board but not sure what to do from there.

The code for the pop-up I was going to use is:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"   
message:@"Do you want to delete everything and go back to product selection?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]
```

Any help/wisdom would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a "Cancel" `UIBarButton` which executes a custom function:

```
- (void)cancelTapped {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:@"Do you want to delete everything and go back to product selection?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes"];
    [alert setTag:1];
    [alert show];
}
```

And listens for the alert to return on:
`- alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`

From there, I would write the logic to hide the page and pop the view.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Delete data and return to lobby
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution (and your edits) @Ramon, but one suggestion for @user3275721… I'd add a tag to the alert so that the didDismissWithButtonIndex action is performed specifically in response to that alert.

Comment: Good suggestion @LyndseyScott! I have made the changes accordingly.

Comment: I have a idea as well. What if I hide the "Product Selection" button just on the editor page and show the "Cancel" button as stated above?  But what file/location would I do this?

Comment: Why use tags? Just store the UIAlertView in a property and compare objects. A lot more robust than an arbitrary tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method (don't forget adding UIAlertViewDelegate on your .h):

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:@"Do you want to delete everything and go back to product selection?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes"]; 
 alert.cancelButtonIndex = 0;

[alert show];



-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    // If user confirmed:
    if (buttonIndex != 0) {

   // Do what you need.
   }
}
```